# How to group by records based on year in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Product which display the data as below:

```
---------------------------------
l  TYPE   l PERIOD l  BALANCE   l
l   Auto  l  2015  l     5      l     
l   Car   l  2015  l     2      l     
l   Bus   l  2015  l     45     l   
l   Auto  l  2016  l     2      l     
l   Car   l  2016  l     6      l     
l   Bus   l  2016  l     50     l  
l   Auto  l  2017  l     12     l     
l   Car   l  2017  l     16     l     
l   Bus   l  2017  l     10     l  
---------------------------------
```

I need to query the this table so that the result is based on the year similar to below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
l TYPE    l BALANCE 2015 l BALANCE 2016 l BALANCE 2017 l
l   Auto  l     5        l       2      l     12       l
l   Car   l     2        l       6      l     16       l
l   Bus   l     45       l       50     l     10       l
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried different queries but no luck.

Your help will be very useful,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use PIVOT in MS Sql Server

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Different products, and the answer might be product specific.)

Comment: If a 2014 row suddenly is inserted, will it be included in the result somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT t.type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN period = 2015 then balance end) as BALANCE_2015,
       MAX(CASE WHEN period = 2016 then balance end) as BALANCE_2016,
       MAX(CASE WHEN period = 2017 then balance end) as BALANCE_2017
FROM Product t
GROUP BY t.type
```

You can add more columns depends on the years you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for the query , but i am not sure about how many years the column "PERIOD" will have so i cant hard code the query with period 2015,2016,2017. is this query can be modified to pick all the year dynamically from the table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT period, type, balance 
    FROM dbo.Product
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(balance)
    FOR period IN ([2015], [2016], [2017]) 
) p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select [Type],[2015] as BALANCE2015,[2016] as BALANce2016,[2017] as BALANCe2017 from 
(
select [Type],[Period],[Balance] from my_table
) as t
pivot 
(
max([Balance]) for Period in ([2015],[2016],[2017])
) as pvt
order by pvt.[Type]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, since the "Period" is a table column which can have any value, the above method of hardcoding values won't be a good idea.

You should generate a dynamic PIVOT query based on the values of Period.

Checkout the following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011591/Dynamic-Pivot-Query-in-SQL-Server

**Update :**

Following query is what you need.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @ColumnName = COALESCE(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(PERIOD)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PERIOD FROM Product) T;

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'SELECT [TYPE], ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM Product ' + 
                        ' PIVOT(SUM([BALANCE]) FOR PERIOD IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable;';

EXEC (@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

**Note:**

I have used SUM as aggregate function in PIVOT, you can change it to MAX or MIN  as per your requirement.